# Spring only allow access if Session Cookie is valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to lock all functions of my API behind an authentication. I managed it so send a Session cookie, but I don't want to check if the cookie is valid in every single function. There gotta be a better way, right? I know I am not supposed to save passwords in clear text, but this code is only for testing purposes.
Login:

```
@RestController
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class OnlineMapping {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @PostMapping(path = "/online")
    public ResponseEntity<?> onlineRequest(@RequestBody OnlineRequest onlineRequest, HttpSession session) {
        User user;
        user = userRepository.findUserByUsernameAndPassword(onlineRequest.username, onlineRequest.password);
        if (user!=null){
            user.setLatestTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

            return new ResponseEntity<>("You are now online, Enjoy!", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("valid", false);
            session.invalidate();
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid login", HttpStatus.valueOf(401));
        }
    }
}
```

Example function:

````java
    public ResponseEntity<?> createMessage(@RequestBody MessageCreateRequest messageCreateRequest, HttpSession session) {
        if (session.getAttribute("valid").equals(true)){ //I dont want this
            Message m = new Message();
            m.setContent(messageCreateRequest.content);
            m.setSenderID(messageCreateRequest.senderID);
            m.setChannelID(messageCreateRequest.channelID);
            m.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            messageRepository.save(m);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Message created!", HttpStatus.OK);
        }//
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid Session", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }```
````

Comment: Why you don't want to use JWT for API authentication?

Comment: I never heard of JWT before, but I'll take a look into it.

Comment: But it doesn't solve my problem though

Comment: you don't need to validate the creds and put something into the session as it would be done by spring security. Link to docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check session cookie validation with Spring Security:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

cookie: JSESSIONID

So in that case you'll have automatic session cookie validation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html

---

**But I would recommend to use JWT Tokens (OAuth 2.0 standard). With Spring Security it's easy to validate and inject Tokens with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server dependency**

Comment: And how? Can you send the function / example